Using Friedman Test for Time-of-Day Analysis on Vaccine Fridge Data?
I worked on a project monitoring vaccine fridge temperatures, collecting data every 30 seconds over two years. I want to compare high temperature anomalies (above 8°C) across different times of the day—Night (4 PM to 12 AM), Day (8 AM to 4 PM), and Evening (4 PM to 12 AM).
To best capture the overall trend over these two years, I plan to use the median number of anomalies for each period (Night, Day, Evening) for each fridge. My idea is to then apply the Friedman test to analyze whether there’s a significant difference in the frequency of these anomalies across the three periods based on these medians.
Is this an appropriate use of the Friedman test, using the median values to reflect the trends? If not, any suggestions for a better method? Any references or examples would be really helpful.

Why do you want to use a significance test for this? Will it come as any surprise to anyone that fridges are opened more often during the day? I would try to visualize the trend instead, and perhaps try to quantify it using a model for counts.

@FransRodenburg
First of all, thank you so much for your response!
My main question wasn’t really about the importance of the conclusions that might come from this analysis, but more about whether the statistical test I mentioned would be valid. From your answer, it seems like the analysis could work—am I understanding that right?
Also, this is the first time I’ve heard of a count model. I’ll look into it more based on what you shared.
Thank you again for taking the time to help me out. Your insights have been really helpful!

How many refrigerators do you have data of?

@FransRodenburg
I initially had data from 1,077 refrigerators. However, since not all of them were used consistently, I filtered the data to include only those that were measured for at least one year, which left me with data from 448 refrigerators.

While it is not inappropriate, I am not a fan of the Friedman test. Trivially, with that many observations, any difference, no matter how small will still be significant. And that's it. That's all the test tells you.
A model, on the other hand, can be used to quantify the difference, as well as visualize it.
Here is how you could do so in R:
# Fit a count regression model
require("lmerTest")
GLMM <- glmer(opened ~ time + (1 | fridge), family = "poisson", data = DF)

# perform ANOVA-style comparisons
require("emmeans")
EMM <- emmeans(GLMM, pairwise ~ time) # ANOVA-style comparisons
EMM$contrasts

#  contrast        estimate      SE  df z.ratio p.value
#  Day - Evening      0.998 0.00955 Inf 104.491  <.0001
#  Day - Night        2.011 0.01442 Inf 139.433  <.0001
#  Evening - Night    1.014 0.01581 Inf  64.094  <.0001
# 
# Results are given on the log (not the response) scale. 
# P value adjustment: tukey method for comparing a family of 3 estimates 

# Visualize the comparison
require("sjPlot")
plot_model(GLMM, type = "pred", terms = "time")



Example data used:
set.seed(2024)
n <- 448
time <- factor(rep(c("Night", "Day", "Evening"), n))
fridge <- factor(rep(1:n, each = 3))
X <- model.matrix(~ time)
Z <- model.matrix(~ fridge)
beta <- c(3, -1, -2)
upsilon <- rnorm(ncol(Z))
eta <- X %*% beta + Z %*% upsilon
y <- rpois(n * 3, exp(eta))
DF <- data.frame(time, fridge, opened = y)
rm(n, time, fridge, X, Z, beta, upsilon, eta, y)


I really appreciate your response. I'm going to study the model in more detail. By the way, I didn't know that small differences can become significant if I have many observations. Could the influence be smaller if I use a parametric method? (for example, repeated measure anova)

@Gallon Both parametric and non-parametric tests will reject the null trivially when the sample size grows very large. You're welcome! If this answers your question you can click the check mark to accept it
